# Adding a validation with for loop using jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

In the below code, I can able to add a div "#template_sec" on click a button. But, I need to add only 10 div, if I try to add div for the 11th time, it should throw an alert message. Help me to resolve the same.

```js
$(window).load(function(){
    addSetImageBlock();
})

function addSetImageBlock(){
    $(".add_set_block").on("click", function(event){
        let template = $($(this).data("target")).clone(true);
        template.removeClass("hidden");
        template.insertBefore(this);
        template.find("#template_sec").hide();
        event.preventDefault();
    })
}
```

```html
<div class="image_video_sec" id="template_sec">
template sec added
</div>
<input type="button" data-target="#template_sec" class="add_set_block txt_btn8 add" tabindex="40">
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a go with this

I wrapped the divs in a container div and added a hidden to the template

```js
const addSetImageBlock = () => {
  const $container = $("#container");
  $(".add_set_block").on("click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    let $template = $($(this).data("target"));
    let len = $container.find(":visible").length;
    if (len === 0) $template.removeAttr("hidden"); // just show
    else if (len < 10) {
      $container.append($template.eq(0).clone(true))
    }
  })
};
$(window).on("load",addSetImageBlock);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div class="image_video_sec template_sec" hidden>
    template sec added
  </div>
</div>
<input type="button" data-target=".template_sec" class="add_set_block txt_btn8 add" tabindex="40" value="click">
```